# Why my code doesn't graph anything?

Tags: plotting

```
f[x_] = 5 x + 3; a = -5; b = 5; dx = (b - a)/n; n = 5

lx = Table[a + i dx, {i, 0, n}]

Show[DiscretePlot[Rectangle[{lx[[i]], 0}, {lx[[i + 1]], f[lx[[i]]]}], {i, 0, n - 1}], 
 Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]]
```

Comment: You can't `DiscretePlot` `Rectangle`, a graphics primitive. Honestly, I don't really understand what you intended to accomplish with this input. And your `Show` syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you're trying to visualize definite integration?

As mentioned by Oleksandr R. in the comment above, `Rectangle` can't be used inside `DiscretePlot`. Besides, the index of list in *Mathematica* always start from `1` so if you want to insist on the using `Rectangle[]`, the code should be something like this:

```
f[x_] = 5 x + 3; a = -5; b = 5; n = 10; dx = (b - a)/n;
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}], {EdgeForm@Thin, Opacity@0.1}~Join~
   Table[{Rectangle[{x, 0}, {x + dx, f[x + dx]}]}, {x, a, b - dx, dx}] // Graphics]
```

[image]

If you want to insist on using `DiscretePlot`, then the code should be something like this:

```
f[x_] = 5 x + 3; a = -5; b = 5; n = 10; dx = (b - a)/n;
Show[DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, a, b, dx}, ExtentSize -> Left, PlotStyle -> EdgeForm@Thin], 
 Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Graphics to plot Rectangles and Show to combine them with the Plot. Notice that the Index for Table should start from 1 and not 0, because list[[0]] gives the Head of that list which is List.

May be this is what you want ?

```
Show[Graphics[
  Table[Rectangle[{lx[[i]], 0}, {lx[[i + 1]], f[lx[[i]]]}], {i, 1, 
    n - 1}]], Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]]
```